# PowerShell Script can't set location to 8.3 filename temp location

Tags: windows, powershell

I am having troubles getting the Windows Update Log on Server 2016. As documented [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/charlesa_us/2015/08/06/windows-10-windowsupdate-log-and-how-to-view-it-with-powershell-or-tracefmt-exe/) Server 2016 now logs Windows update logs differently and to view the logs you need to run a Powershell command from the WindowsUpdate module called Get-WindowsUpdateLog.

The script needs to set the Symbol Cache and it does this by running `'Set-Location $SYM_CACHE'`. The symbol cache variable is set earlier in the piece by this:

```
$WORKDIR = "$env:TEMP\WindowsUpdateLog"
$SYM_CACHE = "$WORKDIR\SymCache"
```

The problem I am getting is that my administrative username is 'secur.tima' and the temp variable is set with the 8.3 filename version of this which is 'C:\Users\SECUR~1.TIM\AppData\Local\Temp\4'

When the script tries to set this as the location it fails with this error:

```
Set-Location : An object at the specified path C:\Users\SECUR~1.TIM does not exist.
At 

    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WindowsUpdate\WindowsUpdateLog.psm1:194 char:5
    +     Set-Location $SYM_CACHE
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I have found this over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782739/how-to-change-to-temp-directory-in-powershell

However that shows how to fix the problem by changing the script. Whilst I could change the script provided by Microsoft, I am wondering if there is some way I can make this work from the server side or change the way that PowerShell handles 8.3 filenames?

Cheers

Tim

Comment: Problem I've had before in Windows with the long filename to 8.3 filename conversion was the assumption that the conversion resulted in `~1` as the expansion replacement. Sometimes there's something else preexisting which has already used the `~1` and I get `~2`, or even higher, instead. Might not be the problem, but a quick. Easy enough to check using `DIR /X` in the normal command shell.

Comment: This problem only exists in PowerShell. If I run 'cd %TEMP%' from a command window it will change to the location successfully.

Comment: __Does__ `C:\Users\SECUR~1.TIM` exist from within PowerShell, or is it `C:\USERS\SECUR~1.TIM`? Does PowerShell even understand the 8.3 filenames?

Comment: That is interesting; If I run `test-path $env:temp` the result is true. However if I run `Set-location $env:temp` the result is: `Set-location : An object at the specified path C:\Users\ADMIN~1.TIM does not exist.`

Comment: Then I'd look at the documentation for `Set-Location` to see if it is 8.3 conversion aware.

Comment: There is no mention of 8.3 in the online documentation for the command [set-location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location).

Comment: Well, looks as if you've narrowed down the problem. Experiment and test further and you'll probably find the solution. Last suggestion is to see if you can find a way to get the long path name into the `TEMP` environment variable. Registry as a last, but possible, option. Good luck.

Comment: As an experiment, try prefacing the path with `\\?\` which will bypass most .net path parsing and go straight to the win32 layer.

Comment: Normally the \\?\ format is for long paths, but it also is good for bypassing issues as noted here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the long version of the 8.3 filename and use it instead. Either:

```perl
$WORKDIR = (Get-Item "$env:TEMP\WindowsUpdateLog").FullName
$SYM_CACHE = "$WORKDIR\SymCache"
```

Or:

```perl
Set-Location (Get-Item $SYM_CACHE).FullName
```

You can read more about this workaround in [my answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/1579897/1077440).

Answer (score 0):

This [technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692752.aspx) seems to indicate that PowerShell doesn't understand 8.3 filenames.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not what the article is saying, I believe it is telling you how to return the file path in the 8.3 format. I know that PowerShell can "understand" 8.3 file paths because `test-path $env:temp` or test-path `C:\users\SECURE~1.TIM` both work.

Answer (score 0):

Make a batch file that does the CD to the temp directory, and then invoke the powershell script from within the batch file?

```
cd %temp%\windowsupdatelog
powershell.exe -f c:\dirname\script.ps1
```